# Trying stop the body from being placed below the sidebar

Tags: html, css, sidebar

http://jsfiddle.net/5V7Q7/3/

What I am trying to do is **stop the body from moving below the sidebar** when there is not enough space for the body next to the sidebar.

I would much prefer that the body becomes hidden off screen. than be placed Below the sidebar.

(Resize the browser to see effects) - Click fiddle link for example of what is happening.

Comment: It is not necessary to use the [jsfiddle] tag or mention in the question title that you have put up a fiddle :)

Comment: Ah k :) Well I have an awesome answer below. And I now know this too. So all is good in the world :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5V7Q7/11/) to do what you want

Basic idea is:

```
#body, #sidebar {display: table-cell;}
```

and **remove all** float:left.

Comment: Yep. Read through it and compared the code. Excellent! Much better than the CSS I wrote yesterday to get it remotely close. Merry Xmas.

Comment: I dont suppose you could make the body horizontal scrollable? :)

Comment: Note that display:table-cell is not recognized by IE7. You will have to write a separate style sheet for IE7

Answer (score 0):

Please note that display:table-cell is not recognized by IE7. You will have to write a separate style sheet for IE7

I've created a different approach, the width is no more of the sidebar ... both are based on percentage. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/5V7Q7/13/) out. If IE7 doesn't bother you then used the solution mentioned above.

Comment: the problem with that is that is just squashes everything, but thainks for bringing to light the IE7 problem.